# Add UIBarButtonItem action programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, webview, action, uibarbuttonitem

I have several UIBarButtonItems, and I want to set the action when you press it programmatically. How can I do this?

EDIT: if it would be possible non-programmatically, please also reply :)

The action is going to Google.com, and the button is the search button in this project: (download): [click here](http://gdscei.com/zEzo.zip)

Answer (score 0):

First create an outlet to the items in IB.  Then you can modify the methods called by using [myItem setTarget:] and [myItem setAction:].

See [target action](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW16)

ETA:  Is there any particular reason you want to do it programmatically?

ETAA:  To do it non-programmatically, make a function with return type IBAction, and argument (id)sender, like so:

```
- (IBAction)myMethod:(id)sender;
```

With whatever implementation you like.  Then, in IB, drag an object object from the Library to the MainWindow.xib window, and in the identity window (cmd-6), give it the class that has your function.  Then, in the connections window of that object (cmd-5), you can drag from your function name to whichever interface object you want.

I strongly suggest you read [mac dev on IB](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.htm).  The connections and bindings section will discuss this particular issue.

Comment: how can i do the same non-programmatically then?

Comment: cause that would be better :)

Comment: but how am i going to go with the action then like you see in the appdelegate.m file in the project download?

Comment: can you give me more in-depth instructions (so really where to put everything and how to do everything) or can you modify my project? Thanks :)

Comment: I think the best thing for you is to do a tutorial or two.  Most basic iPhone apps follow the same pattern, so if you know how to do a real 'Hello World', you'll know how to do your project.  If I just rewrite your code, you won't know the basic design patterns (MVC, for example) that iPhone / Cocoa apps tend to use.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by 'class that has your function'? Do you mean the .m document?

Comment: OK, i did i think so what you wanted me to do... But it still doesn't work :( Can you look at it? Thanks! http://gdscei.com/zEzo%202.zip